# Using Get method to fetch data using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have code that can search information from db without refreshing page (like search input) and it works

```
// check.php
<?php
  include "db.php";
  $show = $_GET['nm'];
  $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post_job WHERE job_title   like('$show%')");
  echo"<table>";
  while($ress = mysql_fetch_array($res))
  {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$ress['first_name'].' '.$ress['last_name'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$ress['gender'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$ress['phone'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
  }
  echo"</table>";
?>
```

for the index.php

```
<form action="" name="form1" method="POST" >
  <label>Search</label><input type="text" name="t1" onKeyUp="aa();">
  <div id="d1"></div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function aa()
  {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","check.php?nm="+document.form1.t1.value, false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    // this id useful for storing response
    document.getElementById("d1").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
</script>
```

Please understand where i am heading to, the above code works but i implement it into codeigniter using below code

```
    //Controller 
public function search()
{
    $data = array();
    $keyword = $this->input->get('check');
    $jobs = $this->profile_model->comSeasrch($keyword);
    $data['show'] = $jobs;
}
```

for the view path, I use thesame input form but I change this `xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo base_url()?>/inquiry/search?check="+document.form1.t1.value, false);` for the javascripts.
Problem: if I type any value to  search it tell's me 404 Page Not Found.
I try to change me config.php to this `$config['uri_protocol']  = 'PATH_INFO';` but not working...
please I need solution

Comment: copy the url and run in browser and see what output u get.

Comment: not using codeigniter i got good result and using it I got 404 Page Not Found. but i just discover something working out but not showing result.... i change the javascript function to this: `xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo site_url('inquiry/search');?>?check="+document.form1.t1.value, false);`